# Parsing incoming JSON in JavaScript - what happens to the "extended parameters"?

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to parse the incoming JSON from XBMC (Eden Beta v3), an example string from XBMC is as follows:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"Player.OnPlay","params":{"data":{"item":{"type":"movie"},"player":{"playerid":1,"speed":1},"title":""},"sender":"xbmc"}}
```

I am using json2.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js to give me the JSON.parse and JSON.stringify functions in my application.

I am using the parse function in my code like this

```
var temp = JSON.parse(data);
```

Which is working fine for the first two properties, "jsonrpc" and "method"... so I can access those like this

```
temp.method
```

returns "Player.OnPlay"

```
temp.jsonrpc
```

returns "2.0"

However, if you look at the string sent by XBMC, it also contains what they refer to as "extended parameters" or "params", I cannot seem to track down what the JSON parser is doing with the rest of the message, or how I can access them in similar ways as the first two properties. If I try

```
params = temp.params
```

or any other way of accessing the params property, I get an Undefined error as there is no such property in the JSON object... I hope this is clear enough for someone to take a stab at helping me out. Will provide any extra info needed...

Thanks

Comment: have you tried temp['params'] ?

Comment: I have just tried this, and it seems to return the same as temp.params: [object Object]

Comment: [object Object] is not undefined... answer incoming.

Comment: @S.Plant: So which is it, do you get `[object Object]` or `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `params` in the JSON data is an object, so you have to access the sub-properties of that.

```
temp.jsonrpc
temp.method
temp.params["data"]["item"]["type"]
temp.params["data"]["player"]["playerid"]
temp.params["data"]["player"]["speed"]
temp.params["data"]["item"]["title"]
temp.params["sender"]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help Fosco, I obviously am just learning this stuff and you pointed me in the exact right direction.